# Exception "A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly" from PowerShell 7.3.1 when using NLog.dll 4.7.10

Tags: powershell, nlog

I'm getting this exception in PowerShell 7.3.1 *sometimes, with some scripts*. I have the same problem whether I run the script in Visual Studio Code (1.74.2) or from a PowerShell (PWSH) prompt:

```
A non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly.
StackTrace: at ProcessItems, C:\git\PerfAndMon-Tools\Scripts\AppDynamics\ServerChecks\Modules\UpdateDnaPathsFunctions.psm1: line 210
at <ScriptBlock><Process>, C:\git\PerfAndMon-Tools\Scripts\AppDynamics\ServerChecks\UpdateDNAPaths.ps1: line 227
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
```

The only .NET assembly I'm using directory is NLog version 4.7.10.13013. I load the NLog.DLL directly in the PowerShell code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($DllPath)
```

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 21H2, OS Build 19044.2364

Some other .NET items I use are:

- System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
- System.Text.StringBuilder
- System.Collections.ArrayList

***Note that I'm not sure the exception is related to NLog. It just seems likely.***

My Pester unit tests for my NLog.psm1 module pass without ever throwing the ICollectible exception.

Comment: Maybe experiment with loading NLog using `AssemblyLoadContext` with constructor-parameter `isCollectible` ? Maybe update to NLog v5 that disables the internal NLog-assembly-loading by default.

Comment: Good ideas. I have moved to NLog 5.x already and that didn't fix it. I'll try the parameter Monday. Thanks!

Comment: I played a bit with AssemblyLoadContext by creating an override class with isCollectible set to true in the constructor. The problem with that is that I had been using a reference like [NLog.LogManager], but I don't think that will work if I load NLog into a custom load context.